# Can we apply CSS using Screen Resolution instead of Viewport?

Tags: html, css, sass, windows-10, media-queries

I want to add CSS style based on screen resolution instead of Viewport.

Here is the case:
My screen resolution is (1980px x 1080px) and if I set Windows 10 "Scale and Layout" to 125% it changes the viewport of the screen and shows that viewport style.
I want to show my media style based on screen resolution, not the viewport.

Currently, I am using these media query for large resolution:

```
// X-Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

// XX-Large devices (larger desktops, 1400px and up)
@media (min-width: 1400px) { ... }
```

Can we achieve this using only CSS not JS?

Screenshots:

**Window 10 Scale 100%** :

[image: Window 10 Scale 100%]

**Viewport at Scale 100%:**

[image]

**Window 10 Scale 125% :**

[image]

**Viewport at Scale 125%:**

[image]

Comment: So you still want to show the `1920` styles on the smaller viewport? Bear in mind that people may enlarge their viewport for accessibility reasons.

Comment: not sure what's the question, screen size and viewport are same it's just the tabs + address bar + bookmark bar which is reducing the height

Comment: When you use windows Layout Scale to "125%" it's changed the viewport which is a completely different thing.

Sorry for the confusion I want to show ```1920px``` style on 1920px Screen resolution also on the viewport. The thing is when we change the windows 10 Layout Scale to "125%" if you check the screen size using JS ```window.outerWidth``` it will show the actual resolution of your screen. But if you check the viewport it will totally different.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey actually that's not true. screen size & viewport can be the same if the pixels of the device and those of the css are equal and most of the times they are not. Take an iPhone XR for example, it has more pixels per inch compared to an iPhone 4 and therefore it will have more pixels as a device than the ones found on CSS compared to an iPhone 4. I'm not sure if I'm making absolute sense here but there are many articles about this that you can find online. viewport and screen resolution are 2 different things, even though they can equal the same amount sometimes based on devices.

Answer (score 5):

To distinguish between changed scaling we need to look at pixel density. And the [resolution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/resolution) media feature can be used for that:

```css
/* used just for the demo*/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* your normal device specific media queries 
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      ...
    }
    @media (min-width: 1400px) {
      ...
    } */


/***********************/

.nonscaling {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background-color: wheat;
  width: fit-content;
}


/* scaling media queries */


/* 1. scale and layout setting at 100% */
@media (resolution: 1dppx) {
  .scale::after {
    content: '100%';
  }
}


/* 2. scale and layout setting at 125% */
@media (resolution: 1.25dppx) {
  .scale::after {
    content: '125%';
  }
  .nonscaling {
    /* offset the scaling */
    /* factor = 100/125 percent */
    transform: scale(0.80);
  }
}


/* 3. scale and layout setting at 150% */
@media (resolution: 1.5dppx) {
  .scale::after {
    content: '150%';
  }
  .nonscaling {
    transform: scale(0.6666);
  }
}


/* 4. scale and layout setting at 175% */
@media (resolution: 1.75dppx) {
  .scale::after {
    content: '175%';
  }
  .nonscaling {
    transform: scale(0.5714);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nonscaling">I will not scale! Period.</div>
<div class="scale">You've scaled: </div>
```

In windows settings change `Scale and layout` setting to 100%, 125%, 150%, or 175%. And see the effect here.
In above snippet we are using `dppx` unit you can use [other units](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#resolution-value). To compensate the scaled elements we are using `transform: scale(..)` feature. You can use [zoom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/zoom) but Firfox [doesn't support it](https://caniuse.com/css-zoom).

**Note:** you can apply `transform:scale(..)` to entire body tag to handle all content with one rule.
Also, you can try combinations of min-resolution, max-resolution and min-width, max-width like `@media (min-width:1200px) and (resolution: 1dppx)`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's simply no way to dismiss the current display scaling settings and work with the resolution only, as it affects the viewport directly. However, you can utilize the following media query:

```
@media screen and (min-resolution: 125dpi) {
   /* Your code here */
}
```

This affects the elements: a) when the display scaling is set to **125% and above**, and b) when the zoom level in your browser is set to **125% or more**.

Another good practise is to give `max-width: 100%;` to both the `html` and `body` tags of your website. This will prevent the various elements from reaching a size which positions them outside the visible viewport (unless of course they are positioned absolutely).